# How to fix the Product Type Inferred error from Scala's WartRemover tool

Tags: scala, scala-2.11, type-annotation

I'm using [WartRemover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover) tool to avoid possible errors in my Scala 2.11 code.

Specifically, I want to know how to fix the **"*Product Type Inferred*"** error.

Looking at the repo documentation, I can only see the failure example, but I would like to know how I'm suppose to fix that error:

https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover#product.

Doing my homework, I end up with this other link that explains how to fix *Type Inference Failures* errors https://blog.cppcabrera.com/posts/scala-wart-remover.html. And I quote "*If you see any of the warnings below, the fix is usually as simple as providing type annotations*" but I don't understand what that means. I really need a concrete example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Product` is a very abstract, high-level type, with very few constraints. When the inferred type is `Product`, that's usually an indication that you made a mistake. E.g. if you have:

```
List((1, "hi", 0.4f), (2, "bye"), (3, "aloha", 7.2f))
```

Then this will compile ok, giving you a `List[Product]`. But, just as when `Any` is inferred, this is probably a bug - you probably meant it to be a `List[(Int, String, Float)]` and meant to have a third entry in the middle tuple.

If you really do want a `List[Product]`, you can avoid getting warned about it by giving the type argument explicitly:

```
List[Product]((1, "hi", 0.4f), (2, "bye"), (3, "aloha", 7.2f))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I understand it a little bit more now. Let's say, I have this expression, that **should** be an (String, JsValue):

`val name: (String, JsValue) = "name" -> teacher.name.map(JsString(_)).getOrElse(JsNull)`

How to I explicitly tell that line I should be an (String, JsValue)? Right now I keep getting the "Inferred type containing Product" error.

BTW: JsString and JsNull inherited from JsValue (spray-json lib)

Comment: Try putting the type annotation on the right hand side of the expression? The only other thing I can suggest is to break up the line so you can see which specific part is causing the problem.

Comment: Indeed, something else was causing the problem. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Type annotation is nothing but explicitly specifying the type, instead of leaving it for the type inference system to work on.

Simplest example in this case can be:

```
val element = 2
```

Currently the inferred type is `Int`, If you want to have more control over the type like specify `Byte, Short, Long, Double`, you can explicitly give the type as:

```
val element: Double = 2
```

Type annotation is also required for public methods as

> Type inference may break encapsulation in these cases, because it depends on internal method and class details

([Source](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html))